# Setting a static DNS nameserver (Debian Squeeze)

Tags: domain-name-system, debian, dhcp, interface

I have a gateway running on Debian Squeeze with 2 network interfaces, one static (internal, eth0) and one DHCP (external, eth1). I have an internal DNS server that I want the gateway to use.

In my **/etc/network/interfaces**, I have eth0 set to static, with a **dns-nameserver** directive, pointing to 192.168.3.4. However, upon rebooting or restarting the networking service, my **/etc/resolv.conf** changes to the DNS server provided by the external DHCP.

How can I get Debian to use my internal DNS server but still obtain a DHCP lease from eth1?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option would be to adjust your `/etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf` file to simply not request the `domain-name-servers` and `domain-name` DHCP options.

You mention that you provided the `dns-nameserver` option in your interfaces file.  Do you actually have the [resolvconf](http://packages.debian.org/squeeze/resolvconf) package installed?  If not, then that setting isn't going to do anything useful, and DHCP will pretty much always over-write the resolv.conf if DNS options are recieved.

If the resolvconf package is installed you can modify the [interface-order](http://stuff.onse.fi/man?program=interface-order&section=5) config to control the order the settings are used.